# How to display images in php from database MYSQLi?

Tags: php, image, mysqli, display

I want to display images in php from my database using Mysqli.
THis is my code in question.php:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="result.php">

                <?php
                $row = mysqli_query( $conn, "select id,question_name,image from questions where category_id=1 and level_id=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");

                $i = 0;
                $j = 1; $k = 1;
                ?>
                <?php while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row) ) {
                     //if ( $i == 0) echo "<div class='cont' id='question_splitter_$j'>";?>
                    <div id='question<?php echo $k;?>' >
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $j;?>"> <?php echo $k?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>

                     <?php echo "<img src='".$result['image']."'/>";?>
                     <input type="text" name="reponse"   required />
                    <br/>

                    </div>
                    <?php

                          $k++;
                     } ?>   
            </form>
```

My table is : 
[image]

But the result is like here:
[image]

can you please help me to display my images correctly?

Comment: If you're in charge of the structure, I'd recommend against storing images in the database for this exact reason. You should instead, store them on disk, and reference them from the database using a path.

Comment: @FrankerZ please can you give me a complete example with mysqli to avoid this problem?

Comment: Just store them on disk. `/question_images/1.png`, and drop the column completely: `<?php echo '<img src="/question_images/', $row['id'], ', '.png" />'; ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)ing the binary data to the browser using the [data-uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP):

```
<?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($result['image']).'" />'; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can create an image.php script, that takes an ID, and outputs the binary data to the browser directly:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM ..."); //**Bind** $_GET['ID'] to the query:
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $row['image'];
```

And in your previous code, access it like:

```
<?php echo '<img src="image.php?id=', $row['id'], '" />'; ?>
```

Comment: Now, i want to insert an image from my form to my database.But the insertion does not work.

Comment: @Sony Then you should consider showing your code, and ask a new question.